# bundle install fails with 'ERROR: Gem bundler not installed'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I have bundler-1.1.3 installed. I have an app that I am trying to get to run. but when I do

```
$cd my_app 
$bundle install
```

the command fails with this error:

```
ERROR: Gem bundler not installed
```

I can run bundle install from anywhere else on the sytem, but not within the app folder.
What could be the problem ?

Comment: is there a .rvmrc file in the directory?

Comment: yes there is. It has a single line in it - rvm 1.9.2-p290@test-set

Comment: so I removed the .rmvrc file and it worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The .rvmrc file in the directory of the app is saying it needs 1.9.2 to run.  RVM has a concept of gem sets that are associated with different versions of ruby on your comptuer.  You probably don't have the bundler gem installed under your 1.9.2 version of ruby but another version, perhaps 1.8.7 or 1.9.3.

```
$ cd my_app
$ rvm use 1.9.2
$ gem install bundle
$ bundle install
```